# Need to export 5 numbers to a file from user input with each number on a different line

Tags: c++

When I run the program it prints each number on the same line.  I need each number to print on a different line.  `endl;` didn't help at all.  It told me I had to add more details because there was too much code so I'm adding all this bulk to the end so it gets through the stupid spam filter.  I have been trying to do this homework for like 2 hours now and I can't figure this one issue with the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream outFile;
  outFile.open("demofile.txt");

  double num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
  cout << "Enter number 1: ";
  cin >> num1;
  cout << "\nEnter number 2: ";
  cin >> num2;
  cout << "\nEnter number 3: ";
  cin >> num3;
  cout << "\nEnter number 4: ";
  cin >> num4;
  cout << "\nEnter number 5: ";
  cin >> num5;


  cout << "\nNow writing...";

  outFile << num1;
  outFile << num2;
  outFile << num3;
  outFile << num4;
  outFile << num5;

  cout << "\nDone.\n";
  outFile.close();

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: _`endl;` didn't help at all._ Huh?? Simply write `outFile << num1 << endl;` etc. Please check the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) before asking such basic question here.

Comment: That was the first thing I did and it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Try \n\r when writing to the file for newlines.

Comment: I wrote 

outFile << num1 << endl; 

and I did the same for each one and it still all prints on the same line.  That was the first thing I did.

Comment: Try `outFile << nul1 << "\n\r";`

Comment: That didn't fix anything either.

Comment: @EvanCarslake That's done by `endl` automatically, when implemented for windows environments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ahh. OP what exactly do you want newlines to be? When the digits are entered? or when it's written to file?

Comment: @JoshuaShelley Show some code that reproduces the problem actually. The code you show, clearly has the problem you describe.

Comment: @EvanCarslake I just need the numbers in the file to be on different lines.  When the numbers are written to the file, they just all need to be on separate lines.

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: If you are using windows : Notepad often shows incorrect text formatting ! I use wordpad when dealing with codes or their input output  and I store them as .txt